# Start/stop button not working correctly iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got into a very noob problem which I can not seem to solve in any way, I am sure I am overlooking something, but cannot figure it out for gods sake!!

Okay, so I have a start/stop button in my app, it should resume the action if the action is paused and pause the action if it is already running. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {

    if(paused){
        [self.progressBar resumeLayer];
        paused = false;
        NSLog(@"resume");
    }

    if(!paused){
        [self.progressBar pauseLayer];
        paused = true;
        NSLog(@"pause");

    }

}
```

**The problem is:** When i run the app and press on the button to pause, it works fine however after that it won't resume at all. After NSLogging to the console, I found that pause is called right after resume.... Why is this?? First: the button is clicked only once, how can it call two opposite methods? Second: Why isn't my BOOL check working?

**EDIT:** If I swap out one of the if statements to an else if, it works fine... Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you using the else instead of two if?

Comment: Because I wanted to know, why it is wrong to use an if statement

Comment: well you can, but you are evaluating twice a condition. If you really want to use two if, put in the first one a return keyword and it will work without problems

Comment: the `if...` statements are totally incorrect logically in that workflow; that would be a miracle if they work in this way.

Comment: Don't you know if...else... ? Just after setting pause to false you test it against false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "paused"? A global variable? An instance variable? I don't know.

Convention is that instance variables should start with an underscore character, which they will do automatically if you just define a property. That way people have at least some idea what is happening.

Convention for BOOL values is YES or NO. Not true or false.

The real bummer is of course a stupid bug in your code. If paused == YES then the first if is executed, paused is set to NO, and then in the next test you check that paused == NO - which it is at this point.

You would have found that easily by stepping through the code in the debugger, line by line.

Comment: Yes!! I am sorry, I forgot that if statements are being called after each other not just the first one if that is already true, I guess this is the case why it works with else if! Thanks! And sorry for the idiotic question.

Answer (score 3):

Please Take Paused variable as BOOL & set with YES & NO

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {

    if(paused){
        [self.progressBar resumeLayer];
        NSLog(@"resume");
    }

    if(!paused){
        [self.progressBar pauseLayer];
        NSLog(@"pause");
    }

    paused = !paused;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the other state in an `else` block instead of having two `if` statements.

The reason why this fails for you now is that, you change the state  of paused to `false` and immediately after the first `if` statement is done you check for `!paused`. That will be true as you just changed it to false.

To fix it, you either can use an `else if (!paused)` statement or just a plain `else` if the paused variable is a boolean.

Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {

    if(paused){
        [self.progressBar resumeLayer];
        paused = false;
        NSLog(@"resume");
    } else {
        [self.progressBar pauseLayer];
        paused = true;
        NSLog(@"pause");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Declare first BOOL variable in @interface ViewController ()
Ex. bool start;
2) Initialize BOOL variable in viewDidLoad method Like this start = YES;
3) now write code in button Action Like this

- (IBAction)btnPause:(UIButton *)btn {
    if (start == YES)
    {
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        start = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        start = YES;
    }
}

// Its change button background color but you can use your Logic.
```